# Mac web sharing: default directory listing name length

Tags: apache, macos, unix

I'm sharing a folder over the web using Mac's Web Sharing. Some file names are long and they are concatenated.  How do I change the default directory name listing length on a Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit an .htaccess file in the directory and use IndexOptions to set name length and description length.